# How do I get value of a dynamically created radio button in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, radio-button

Here is the code in more detail. I'm still getting undefined. I understand if I get undefined the first time I hit next button because the user hasn't selected the radio button.

```js
 var index = 0;

 function updateAnswers( t ) {
      for(i=1;i<answers.length;i++){
            $("#answerTable").append("<tr><td>" + String.fromCharCode(64+i) + ")<input type='radio' id='ans'" + i + "' name='ansRadio' value='" + String.fromCharCode(64+i) + "' />" + answers[t][i] + "</td></tr>");
      }
}

 $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 750,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Next": function() {                    
                updateAnswers(index);
                $( "#testanswers tbody" ).append( "<tr><td>" + $("input[type='radio'][name='ansRadio']:checked").val()) + "</td></tr>" );
                index++;                
            }
        }           
});
```

```html
<div id="dialog-form">
   <form>
     <table id="answerTable">            
     </table>
   </form>
</div>



<table id="testanswers" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
   <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
          <th>Answer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your full code

Comment: please check for valid markup of a TABLE element

Comment: Is the table elements okay in this code?

Comment: I fixed the table elements and moved the the function call below the radio append and it works now. Thanks. I do not have the reputation points to add rep points, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking your code I think you are not adding the radio value in a correct position of the table you need create a row and col

Change by:

```
function() {                    
    $( "#testanswers tbody" ).append( "<tr><td>" + $("input[type='radio'][name='ansRadio']:checked").val() + "</td></tr>");

}
```

Or:

```
function() {                    
         $( "#specificColId" ).append( $("input[type='radio'][name='ansRadio']:checked").val());
}
```

Comment: Does the edited code address this? I still get undefined whenever hitting next(I know it should be undefined first time hitting next because the radios have not been created yet).

Comment: I fixed the table elements and moved the the function call below the radio append and it works now. Thanks. I do not have the reputation points to add rep points, though.